# Can I change the default __add__ method in Python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Is it possible to change the default `__add__` method to do something else than just add?

For example, if the goal is with this line:
`5+5` get `The answer is 10` or anything else like `0` by changing `__add__` to be `x-y` instead of `x+y`?

I know I can change `__add__` in my own classes:

```
class Vec():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.x, self.y}'

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return Vec(self.x,self.y)

    
v1 = Vec(1,2)
v2 = Vec(5,3)

v1+v2
# (6, 5)
```

Can I somehow target the default `__add__` method to change its behaviour? I intuitively think that `__add__` is defined in each default data type to return specific results, but then again, the `__add__` method is what we address when changing it for a specific class, so, is it possible to change the main `__add__` logic?

Something along these lines?

```
class __add__():
    ...
```

Comment: There is no "default", only what is (or might be) inherited from a parent. `object.__add__` isn't defined, so effectively nearly every standard class that supports addition defines it from scratch.

Comment: change for your own classes: yeah just write the `__add__` method to do something different. Change behaviour for **built-in types**: No, at least not without recompiling python after changing the C source code.

Comment: Thank you, can I find how standard classes define addition from scratch? If so, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: may I ask: Why? Why do you want addition to do subtraction? Do you have any realistic goal or is this a purely theoretical question? [There are so many overloadable methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) surely if you have a custom behaviour you can use something like [`x << y`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lshift__)

Comment: Sure, this is purely theoretical, I am trying to grasp the foundation of built-in types and their limitations and would like to read how the addition / subtraction / etc is defined in the very base level of Python, I assume when its compiled.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis If you looking for the _very base_ level, you may want to check out the [source for CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython). You can, for instance, find the implementation of `int` addition [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L3073), that of `list` addition [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L500), tuple addition [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L508), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for information about how the C level built-ins are defined you would want to look at [some of the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L1865), note that I'm linking specifically to floats but the structure exists for all number types:

```c
static PyNumberMethods float_as_number = {
    float_add,          /* nb_add */
    float_sub,          /* nb_subtract */
    float_mul,          /* nb_multiply */
```

this is the structure for all the C function pointers that implement number methods, (for floats in this case) each builtin type that defines any number related methods will define a `PyNumberMethods` structure, this is then used in the formal [definition of the type:](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L1912)

```c
PyTypeObject PyFloat_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "float",
    sizeof(PyFloatObject),
   
    ...
        
    &float_as_number,                           /* tp_as_number */
```

the `PyTypeObject` represents all the relevant information needed to construct the `float` object in python, (or equivalently, `int` or `str` etc.) containing all the methods, attributes, and necessary meta-data to work as a python type.  So if you really wanted to change adding floats to instead do another well defined task you'd just change it to point to the other function:

```c
static PyNumberMethods float_as_number = {
    float_sub,          /* nb_add.  overrides to do subtraction because I want to break everything >:D */
    float_sub,          /* nb_subtract */
```

If you wanted to write your own behaviour you could write your own function and point to it in this structure instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can overload whatever in user defined classes.

```py
class Vec():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.x, self.y}'

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y
        return Vec(self.x,self.y)

    
v1 = Vec(1,2)
v2 = Vec(5,3)

print(v1+v2)

# using lambda function
Vec.__add__ = lambda self,other: Vec(self.x-other.x,self.y-other.y)
print(v1+v2)

# using "normal" function
def add(self,other):
    self.x -= other.x
    self.y -= other.y
    return Vec(self.x,self.y)
Vec.__add__ = add
print(v1+v2)
```

Will not work for built-in types, e.g. resulting in `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'set'`

Also please note that your implementation of `__add__` modifies the original instance, which I don't like.. (just my note)

Comment: Thank you, I have a question, what do you mean that my `__add__` implementation modifies the original instance? I understand that only objects that are made out of class `Vec` will have the `__add__` method modified, but everything else will work as before when using `__add__` method. I understand that original instance is class `Vec`, right?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis the `__add__` changes `self.x` and `self.y`, check `v1` after doing the addition with your current implementation.

Comment: This works for v1 + v2, but gives an error for more than two instances, like v1 + v2 + v3 + ... + vn. What if I wanted to add as many instances as I wanted?

Comment: @Jonas I have tested it with 3 instances and it worked OK. What is the actual code? What error? What python version? ... maybe a topic for a new question

Comment: The problem original instance getting modified can be avoided by simply returning `return Vec(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)`